# create event for notifying completed in another event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have mainviewmodel where it makes a collection of itemviewmodel and binds that data to a longlist in Mainpage.xaml. Now in the process of making a collection of ItemViewModel I am making a web request and when that downloads I would make a list.

*I wanted to know in MainPage as when this **download** finishes.*

**MainViewModel**

```
public void LoadData()
    {
        if (this.CanLoad)
        {
            WebClient dealsOfDay = new WebClient();
            dealsOfDay.DownloadStringCompleted += dealsOfDay_DownloadStringCompleted;
            dealsOfDay.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://loadsomedata.php"));
        }
        else
        {
            this.IsDataLoaded = false;
        }
    }

void dealsOfDay_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
        {

            var deals=//something making  a collection.

            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(deals);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");

            this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**
Inside the constructor I would set this.

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have no need for `bool` `IsDataLoaded`. Instead that create event in `MainViewModel` and register in Main page.

```
public event EventHandler DataLoadedEvent;
void dealsOfDay_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
    {

        var deals=//something making  a collection.

        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(deals);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");

        if ( DataLoadedEvent != null)
        {
            DataLoadedEvent(this, new EventHandler());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Now in MainPage constructor register this event.

```
App.ViewModel.DataLoadedEvent += new EventHandler(data_loadedEvent);


void data_loadedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     App.ViewModel.LoadData();
}
```

Comment: I got a doubt here. You made a call to DataLoadedEvent(this,..). Now are you calling a method or creating a new object here?? and inside the event the LoadData method is present. LoadData method is where i would call the webclient. So there is no possibilty that this required here. Indeed my post processing methods should be there i think.

Comment: Oh yes, I got it. Thank you very much for the answer. That is just calling the delegate. Isn't it?

Comment: Yup, its just calling the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Remember also that you can **subscribe more methods** to `DownloadStringCompleted` - and they will be fired, so maybe there is no need to create new event. Also in many cases you can just perform actions in `dealsOfDay_DownloadStringCompleted`.

But if you want to make an Event which will be fired when DownloadCompletes it can look like this:

Create a delegate:

```
public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, StatusEventArgs e);
public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;
```

For this purpose you need somewhere to define StatusEventArgs Class:

```
public class StatusEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Status { get; private set; }

    public StatusEventArgs(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Then your method can look like this:

```
private void UpdateStatus(string status)
{
   if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

   StatusEventArgs args = new StatusEventArgs(status);
   OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
}
```

Then you can freely subscribe to that event and put in your `dealsOfDay_DownloadStringCompleted`:

```
UpdateStatus("Downloaded");
```

Comment: This event is created in my ViewModel only and can be subscribed in it only. But I want the event subscription to be in another View.

Comment: @max I think it can be done in many ways and everything depends on your needs. I'm glad you have found soultion.

Comment: Well, I kinda used both the methods to achieve my solution. But the one I accepted suits to my application. Thank you for your response(quick).